# Load 1000 images smartly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loading

I have like 1000 images on the same page. Unfortunately, I can't use sprites on them, as the number of images increases continuously. So you can imagine it sends 1000 HTTP requests, so it takes lots of time for the images to load plus it's not good experience for the visitors.

I have seen one of the scripts named as *Lazy Load*, but I was thinking if there is a ***smarter way*** of loading images (good regarding [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization), loads images faster and is good for user experience).

Is there a way out to load images in a better way?

To elaborate:

I have to load all 1000 images on the same page, there is no other way out. What is it going to be like or for what am I going to use it for, I have actually made a *test page* for you at http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/03/testing-2_04.html.

As you can see, I am using the [jQuery Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) plugin made by Jacek Galanciak. I don't have good relations with this plugin as if I am going to add jQuery or a script to it. It will ask for a callback function which is a blind spot for me. (That's why I made a CSS tooltip for it :D)

I have many pictures in my test page but not 1000. When they will be 1000, it will be a mess. So I don't know how to deal with 1000 images in this case. (By the way THANKS TO YOU ALL FOR LOVELY COMMENTS)

Comment: will the user even be able to differentiate 1000 images on a single page?

Comment: Don't have that many images on a single page.

Comment: I don't really think there is any smarter way than the way LazyLoad do it as it loads them when they are actually needed and it's achieve in a very simple way already.

Comment: Not sure why and how you want these images to appear. You may need to think about the user interaction before you go and explore the solution.

Comment: loading 1000 images in a single page is not a "smart" move.

Comment: LazyLoad would do the best possible AFAIK but is there any specific reason you want 1000 images on a single page??? if there is any then we can think of some other work around if possible

Comment: My initial thought is that if you're loading 1000 images, then there's no real way to ease that pain. It's going to hurt. That said, perhaps if you explained what those 1000 images are for, there may be some sort of solution.

Comment: What a ridiculous number of images on a page! Reduce the number of images.

Comment: If the images are large (vs thumbnail sized) it's also abusive to some browsers. Opera and Firefox will suffer severe UI lag if they don't end up freezing entirely. In FF's case the problem is that it tries to decode every image on the page and store a bitmap version in memory. A 1024x768 image will turn into a 3MB bitmap; do that a few hundred or a thousand times and you'll crash into the 32bit process memory limit.

Comment: @DanNeely well I have tried my best and have kept the px to 90 x 90 and the size of image stays around 4KB but still it would mean 4MB which is a SHOCKING news for me.

Comment: @shahfaisalkhan  (Excepting old/very low end) systems, the display system uses 4 bytes per pixel (1 byte for each of colors, the 4th is commonly used for transparency but is generally allocated even for opaque images to optimize memory access).  Decoded your images would be about 32k each, or about 32MB for the entire set.

Answer (score 20):

Very few use cases support serving hundreds or thousands of images on a single page. One such case is Google Images. This is how to do it right:

https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=jeff+atwood

1. **Lazy load images** This is a requirement. If the images are below the fold (outside the visible document area) there's no reason to load them.
2. **Use pagination** Google Images breaks up results into pages where only a handful of images are loaded at the time. Google also uses some JavaScript-fu to implement an *infinite scroll* - once the browser gets close to the bottom of the current results, it sends a request to load more result pages and injects them at the bottom of the page.
3. **SEO: No JavaScript, No Problem** Visit the Google Images link again, but with JavaScript turned off. You can still browse through the results pages - there's about 15 images per page. Search engines can index this image content.
4. **Maximum Image Display** Once more than 150+ images are being displayed put a button at the bottom of the page to "Load More Results" - this button reloads the entire page, but starts at the 151st image instead of the 1st. Every image the browser has to draw takes up more memory & CPU cycles. Scrolling a long list can quickly bring a mobile browser or modest desktop to crawl.

Loading thousands of images is bad - it will tax your server to ruing the user experience. This is true of any large data set that a user wants to browse.

Comment: Which one should I use Infinite Scrolling script or Jail Script? As I don't know which one will suit me in this scenario, where there are chances that users will scroll down.

Comment: For your case I'd use lazy loading + pagination. Limit the number of images per page and only load them when they're in their in the view area. You can add in eternal scrolling later - as an eternal scroll is essentially auto-pagination (loads the next few pages of results once the user gets close to the end of the current page of results).

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can think of:

**Don't do this**. Don't load 1000 images on one site, and **do use** some kind of lazy loading or pagination.

Nevertheless, one idea, not sure if it fits, as you never gave the concrete use case:
run a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to stitch the images together to a/some bigger image(s) every X minutes depending on your needs. Use the bigger image as you would use a sprite solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, I think year 2010, the [Singapore National Day parade](http://www.ndp.org.sg/) site frontpage had multiple pictures, like 20 x 20 of them. Every day during peak hours the database (MySQL) and web server (Apache) went down.

The development team then deployed `memcached` to resolve the issue.

Comment: sure, that will solve the server side. how about the client side? not only will it take long, it will kill the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) to render these images when the user scrolls the page load set of images on the fly.

This is a complex way to do where you load af few (N number of) images first and check that the user has not scrolled till few rows of images are left before `containerNode.offsetHeight`. If the user scrolls down that limit you create N number of image tags for the next n images to be loaded.

This N can be varied based upon the image file size or dimensions.

Comment: The question is explicit that it is looking for something "smarter" than lazy loading.

Comment: I felt the dev donot understand the concept of lazyloading as this is a very smart way to display such huge list of images ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the plugin [QueryLoader 2](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/). It won't help you to load them quicker - as you say, the increase in number - but it will show a "loading" screen while elements are still loading, and may provide you with a better user experience.

That or do as in some other answers and load them as you scroll down.