# pagination php without mysql (or any other database)

Tags: php, pagination

Hello I am pretty new at php and stuff so i am trying my best

I have a site with over 200 images and i want to split them in pages so i try to pagination but i only have the images not a database soo my code so far

```
   $iPicturesPerSite = 10;

    $output = '';
    $files = glob('../images/'.$sSearchFor.'*.{jpg,png,gif}',GLOB_BRACE);

    $iSite = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['iSite']) && is_numeric($_GET['iSite']) && $_GET['iSite'] > 0){
        $iSite = $_GET['iSite'];
    }
  $iMaxBildNummer = $iPicturesPerSite * $iSite;
    if($iMaxBildNummer > sizeof($files)){
        $iMaxBildNummer = sizeof($files);
    }
    for($i=(($iPicturesPerSite*$iSite)-$iPicturesPerSite); $i<$iMaxBildNummer; $i++){
        $size = getimagesize($files[$i]);
        $output = $output.$this->_simpleTpl("tpl/item.tpl",array(
                'showName'=> basename($files[$i]),
                'imagewidth' => $this->width,
                'fileName'=>'images/'.basename($files[$i]),
                'resolution'=>$size[0]."x".$size[1],
                'fileSize' => round(filesize($files[$i])/1024),
                'link' => '.link to file='.$files[$i]));
  }
    return $output;
}
```

all i get so far is that i can see 10 pic at the first page (depens on what i put in iPicturesPerSite). but now i need to add the **next/prev** link lines and i need to split the pic to the links.

i am trying since 2 days but thats all i got and i am not getting better :( any links/help would be nice. (this is not the full code i have some other stuff in it and its a **html + php** data so i dont use any php code in the html data)

tried this but didnt work. i think i still need more lerning in php because i dont know how to do it. thanks anyway

EDIT:

```
     $total_data = count($files);       


        $page = isset($_GET['page'])?intval($_GET['page']):1;     // GETTING PAGE NUMBER FROM URL

        if(empty($page) || $page==1) {
            $start_val = 0;
            $end_val = $iPicturesPerSite - 1;
        }
        else {
            $start_val = ($page * $iPicturesPerSite) - $iPicturesPerSite;
            $end_val = $start_val + ($iPicturesPerSite - 1);
        }




        for($i=$start_val;$i<=$end_val;$i++){
            echo $files[$i].' ';
        }


        $less_than = $total_data/$iPicturesPerSite;
        if($less_than>intval($less_than)) $less_than = $less_than + 1;

        if($total_data>1) {
            echo '<div class="pagination">';
            echo ($page-1)>0?'<a href="?page='.($page-1).'">Previous</a>&nbsp;':'Previous&nbsp;';
            for($i=1;$i<=$less_than;$i++){
                if($page==$i) echo '<a class="paginator linkno">';
                else echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'" class="paginator">';
                echo $i;
                echo '</a>&nbsp;';
            }
            echo ($page+1)<=$less_than?'<a href="?page='.($page+1).'">Next</a>':'Next';
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

almost. now i have the right numbers bu i only can see 1 image and the rest are in char (not pic its more ../images/ui-bg_diagonals-medium_20_d34d17_40x40 - Kopie (2).png ../images/ui-bg_d)

Comment: Perhaps you may want to output the whole 200 pictures per page, and then hide/show them using JavaScript, thus simulating pagination.

Comment: Why without mysql? You can menage it on csv file, do you?

Comment: Like facebook?no i would like to put them this way > 10images/page or maybe more. i will decide how many later but first i need to create the fuction for it. i dont know how to start right now i am still learing. no mysql because i dont use any database right now i just have a folder full of images.

Comment: @Piskvor this way will significantly slow down you application load time, since you need to make separate request for every Image. I wouldn't recommend doing this for images.

Comment: Why did i get a downvote? iam really trying everything i can and i already search a lot in the past days. i only ask here for help because i dont know what to do.

Comment: @edvinas.me: I don't understand: How exactly is the browser *not* making a separate HTTP request for each image anyway? Also, how is "now load me these 10 images which were hitherto not shown on the current webpage" significantly different from "now load me these 10 images which were hitherto not referenced at all"? Both will utilize the same requests, with the same keepalive/pipelining.

Comment: @edvinas.me: If you mean "you need to load all the 200 images at start" - not necessarily: since you're using JS anyway, you could dynamically load only those images which are on the current page. See e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137758/load-1000-images-smartly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you coded this yourself or not, but I notice the pagination technique built in right there. `iSite` is basically your page number and you have to use this to construct next/previous links.

Next page link would be `page.php?iSite=<?php echo $iSite+1 ?>`

For previous it would be `page.php?iSite=<?php echo $iSite-1 ?>`

Comment: yes i did that myself in the past 2 days( iam using php for 3-4 weeks now and this is pretty hard for me) Thank you i will give it a try

Comment: I checked your edit. You should `echo` outside the `for` loop.