# how to handle 1000+ images in one web page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading, pageload

Currently i am making a web application where admin will upload pictures it could be 1000 of images of average 130kb and user will login and check and select the images he wants to be printed. What i want to ask is that when I will load 1000 pictures in one page will my page get slow and how to handle these type of situations.
I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: Load lets say 30 images at a time, and load 30 more when the user has scrolled to the bottom, and keep repeating the task.

Comment: if you google your question, you find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137758/load-1000-images-smartly

Answer (score 0):

You can load your entire page first with loading placeholders in place of images......then once your page is loaded start loading the images....so the user can keep working on the page while the images load.....Basically lazy load your images.